# Grub2 Screen Navigation

Tags: grub2, navigation

Once I select a submenu from the main menu in grub (I.E.) "Previous Linux Versions" it seems I'm forced to only choose an item in the submenu without no option to navigate up to the main menu again. Is there a keystroke I'm missing to 'abort' a submenu and go back to the main screen?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to use the 'Esc' key? With this key you can abort the submenu selection.

Comment: I thought I did, I'll experiment again...

Comment: ESC works!
Sorry but I thought I'd tried it [embarrassed].
THANX...

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to navigate to a previous menu. You can do this if you've entered the editor for a commend list, also.

Comment: ESC works!
Sorry but I thought I'd tried it [embarrassed].
THANX to both you and slashcrack(above)...